# Convert an array of double value in to a character buffer

Tags: c, string, bit-shift

I need to send an array of 4 double value in to a character buffer of size 8 byte  and also would like to extract the value from the character array in to double value for its usage.

I am trying with the below code but not getting correct output as char `str` is of size 8 byte is too little to store 4 double value !!

Ex:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
    {
     char str[8]={'\0'};
     double x=-10.456678,p=12.678906,q=80.8956876,r=360.67,y,z,h,k;
     sprintf(&str[0],"%2.6f",x);
     sprintf(&str[1],"%2.6f",p);
     sprintf(&str[2],"%2.6f",q);
     sprintf(&str[3],%3.4f",r);
     //Extracting the same from str
     y=atof((char *)&str[0]);
     z=atof((char *)&str[1]);
     h=atof((char *)&str[2]);
     k=atof((char *)&str[3]);

     printf("\ny= %2.6f",y);
     printf("\nz= %2.6f",z);
     printf("\nh= %2.6f",h);
     printf("\nk= %2.6f",k);
     return 0;
 }
```

Could anyone please answer how do I send 4 double value in to a character 
 array of 8 byte ?

Comment: minus 1:Format your code. What is this? What are you trying to ask?

Comment: "I need to send an array of 4 double value in to a character buffer of size 8 byte". Well you can't. The memory size of a double is 8 bytes. You'd need at least 32 bytes to fit 4 of them.

Comment: You need `sizeof(double) *  4` bytes to hold the doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Well storing this many data into so little memory is impossible. But could you explain more about what you want to do in the end, because right now I don't understand why you need to transform numbers into strings and transform them back again ?

If you only want to have numbers stored as strings, you could use for example an array of strings which store each number :

```
char numbers[4][20];
sprintf(numbers[0], "%f", x);
...
printf("%s", numbers[0]);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Certainly `[20]` will be insufficient for values like  `1e30`.  `"%f"` is not a good general solution especially  for about half the `double`  which are quite small.

Comment: The size `[20]` was chosen as an example, and the author doesn't seem to use big numbers, but indeed you will need more space for bigger numbers.